# Audio bitrate changes when converting from mkv to mp4 in ffmpeg

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ffmpeg, 64-bit

Whenever I convert mkv x264 to mp4, the audio bitrate changes to 128kbps aac when the original bitrate is 265kbps.

I did the `-c:a copy` to just copy the audio but it changes the bitrate.
And when I set `-b:a 256kbps` it doesn't really go that way only around 252 to 255.

Can anyone tell me the right code to really follow the bit rate of audio?

Comment: It shouldn't change the bitrate if you use `-c:a copy`. How are you determining the audio bitrate? Show your actual ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: Yeah if I use the same container (mkv) in the output file, but if I change it like (mp4) the bitrate changes, from 256kbps to 128kbps.

Comment: What are you using to show the bitrate?

Comment: What do you mean about what I am using?

Comment: What tool or program are you using to find out the bitrate? Because maybe that is the problem and not ffmpeg.

Comment: Movavi Video Converter

Comment: I wouldn't trust that. movavi made by a known [spammer and GPL license violator](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3988).

Comment: Okay noted, but how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not convinced there is an issue (with ffmpeg). How can we duplicate the issue? You should show your command and the complete log. Use another tool to determine the bitrate.